# Combined INSERT SELECT Oracle-Query does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, max, sql-insert, navicat

I have the following query, which normally should work, but does not work with my navicat database magagement software:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(ID_NO, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7, COLUMN8, COLUMN9, COLUMN10, COLUMN11, DDATE_IN) VALUES(SELECT ID_NO+1 AS ID_NO FROM ((SELECT MAX( ID_NO ) as ID_NO FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID_NO ORDER BY ID_NO DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1), 'Value2', 'Value3', 1, 1, 1, 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6', 'Value7', 'Value8', 'Value9', TO_DATE('05.07.2020 10:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

The SELECT query should take the highest already existing ID_NO (ID number) of TABLE1 and add 1 and write this in the INSERT statement.So the ID_NO has to be iterated which each new INSERT in that table.

If I write the SELECT statement as a single statement in navicat without the INSERT prompt it works. But I want to put it in the INSERT prompt string. I have to have the combined query in a single string, because I use a C# code which sends the oracle query string to the database and that works only with one single string. What is wrong here? I am stuck since a few days and I can not see the mistake.

Edit: I found the mistake by myself. I forgot to put the SELECT Statement into brackets, i.e. into "()". I edited the code of my first post. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I forgot to set the SELECT Statement into brackets, i.e. into "()". I edited my code. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

> The `SELECT` query should take the highest already existing `ID_NO` (ID number) of `TABLE1` and add `1` and write this in the `INSERT` statement.

You seem to be overcomplicating this. I think you want the `insert ... select` syntax with an aggregate query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(
    ID_NO, 
    COLUMN1, 
    COLUMN2, 
    COLUMN3, 
    COLUMN4, 
    COLUMN5, 
    COLUMN6, 
    COLUMN7, 
    COLUMN8, 
    COLUMN9, 
    COLUMN10, 
    COLUMN11, 
    DDATE_IN
) 
SELECT 
    COALESCE(MAXID_NO), 0) + 1,
    'Value2', 
    'Value3', 
    1, 
    1, 
    1, 
    'Value4', 
    'Value5', 
    'Value6', 
    'Value7', 
    'Value8', 
    'Value9', 
    TO_DATE('05.07.2020 10:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM TABLE1
```

Note that this is a rather inefficient way to proceed, since it requires scaning the table for each and every `insert`. If you can live with gaps, then it would be simpler to use a sequence instead.

Comment: I got it. I forgot to set the SELECT Statement into bracket, i.e. into "()". I edited my code. This thread can be closed. It works now. For a next revision of my C# program I try to use a sequence instead, as you suggested.

Comment: @ GMB: No it did not. The FROM Statement is also in the wrong place in your Oracle Command. It did not work in NaviCat. I just changed my Oracle Command with the brackets. I wanted to have the oracle command in one line. A string command with one line because I use this in a C# program, which needs this.